# Referenced Dll's not found in Team Foundation Service (or: nuget packages not available on other pc)

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

when I create a build for the Team Foundation Service, I get all kind of reference dll's not found exceptions.

These references are added by nugget packages.

I've added the 'package restore' option on the solution which added 3 files in a .NuGet folder.

EDIT

When i got the solution from TFS on another pc, i got the same errors (missing dll's), so it's not only the TFS build service having problems.

The missing dll's are are missing files from installed nuget packages (some are part of the default VS template, Unity was a package i added later), which (the packages) are added on the first pc, but then are missing on the next pc (that's why i added the 'or' in the title of this question)

How can i get the Nuget added files on pc2 too?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've found a solution by now. I write this just to provide an answer for this question.

To have NuGet packages automatically downloaded on another PC, you need to enable NuGet package restore on build. You do this in two steps:

1. Right click the solution and select Enable NuGet Package Restore.
   This will add a .nuget solution folder with NuGet.Config, NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets underneath it. These files should actually be checked in to source control, but the binary file is tiny. It will also modify the MSBuild scripts in all projects of the solution to import the NuGet.targets file to hook NuGet into the build process.
2. In Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings make sure the option 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build' is checked. 
   This step must be done on all machines.

Now the BuildDependsOn property of all project build scripts should make the RestorePackages target in NuGet.targets kick in and download missing packages before you get build errors for missing references.